# extract paragraph from a txt file at SDcard android

Tags: java, android, file, extract

I was looking for help as i want to extract a String paragraph from a .txt file from SDcard in adnroid. I have the file but can't extract just a part of it. For example, I have this file:

```
Mother (mamá)
Father (papá)
Daughter (hija)
Son (hijo)
Sister (hermana)
Brother (hermano)
Grandmother (abuela)
Grandfather (abuelo)
Aunt (tia)
Uncle (tio)
Nephew (sobrino)
Niece (sobrina)
Cousin (primo "o" prima)
Wife (esposa)
Husband (esposo)
NOTA: Al añadir las palabras inglesas "in law" se forman nuevas palabras que tambien deben ser incluidas en este vocabulario para referirnos a "La familia"
Mother in law (*suegra)
Father in law (*suegro)
Sister in law (*cuñaada)
Brother in law (*cuñado)
gual sucede con la palabra "step" antepuesta a algunas palabras inglesas, para referirnos a otro parentesco familiar, resultado de la relacion de nuestros padres con otras parejas (como en el caso de divorcios,muerte de alguno de ellos,etc)
Step mother (*madrastra)
Step father (*padrastro)
Step sister (*hermanastra)
Step brother (*hermanastro)
```

and just nned to extracto from "Son" until "Niece"

my code is:

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    if (!estado.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        tv.setText("No SDcard");
        finish();
    }

    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File puntero = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator
            + "manualandroid.txt");
    try {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(new FileReader(puntero));
        StringBuilder texto = new StringBuilder();
        String linea;
        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        while (lector.hasNext()) {
            linea = lector.nextLine();
            if (linea.contains("Son") && linea.contains("Niece") {
                texto.append(linea);
                texto.append("\n");
            }
        }
        lector.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and it just show me the line that contains "Son" and "Niece", I'm new at this. Can someone help me pleas? y need to read :

```
Son (hijo)
Sister (hermana)
Brother (hermano)
Grandmother (abuela)
Grandfather (abuelo)
Aunt (tia)
Uncle (tio)
Nephew (sobrino)
Niece (sobrina)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some more context? What is that paragraph for? What are you trying to do? It looks to me as if there was a better solution than cutting out a paragraph from a text file.

Comment: I want to do a ListView with differents titles. Every Title has his own content. In this example I want to show the Family members, another option in the ListView will be "The Animals", and so on....but I only have a txt file tha I must use. So for every chapter I have to "cut" especifics paragraphs. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   int withinRange = -1;
   while (lector.hasNext()) {
        linea = lector.nextLine();

        if (linea.contains("Son"))
           withinRange =0;
        if (withinRange == 0) {
            texto.append(linea);
            texto.append("\n");
        }
        if (linea.contains("Niece"))
           withinRange = 1;
   }
```